# При компиляции функция удаляется

Tags: c, компилятор, avr-gcc

Код для микроконтроллера с ядром AVR 
Функция принимает булевое значение, порт и номер пина, меняет бит в порте на соответствующий значению.

```
   void chgBit(char value, char port, char pin)
{
    if((value))
    {
        port |= _BV(pin);
    }
    else
    {
        port &=~ _BV(pin);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
     chgBit(1,PORTB,1);
     chgBit(0,PORTB,1);
     chgBit(0,PORTB,1);
     chgBit(1,PORTB,1);
```

В дизассемблере выглядит как

```
     chgBit(1,PORTB,1);
00000051  IN R24,0x18       In from I/O location 
     chgBit(0,PORTB,1);
00000052  IN R24,0x18       In from I/O location 
     chgBit(0,PORTB,1);
00000053  IN R24,0x18       In from I/O location 
     chgBit(1,PORTB,1);
00000054  IN R24,0x18       In from I/O location
```

В своих скудных познаниях, я приблизительно понимаю почему это происходит, но вот как исправить, не понимаю.

Comment: Это какой-то невалидный код: `port setBit(pin);`. Что Вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: сделано, извиняюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция "ничего не делает". У нее нет ни результата, ни внешних побочных эффектов (т.е. *наблюдаемого поведения*). Неудивительно, что функция удаляется оптимизирующим компилятором.

Все, что делает ваша функция - это модифицирует свою локальную переменную `port`. Так как это просто локальная переменная, с "внешним миром" никак не взаимодействующая и более ни на что не влияющая, компилятор не считает необходимым сохранять манипуляции над этой переменной в финальном коде.

Все, что видит компилятор, это то - то параметр `port` при вызове функции инициализируется значением порта `PORTB`, что выливается в физическое чтение значения из соответствующего аппаратного порта. Такое чтение значения компилятор расценивает как часть *наблюдаемого поведения* программы. Поэтому данная операция сохраняется в финальном коде. В результате все, что остается от ваших четырех вызовов `chgBit` - это четыре чтения порта `PORTB`.

---

http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/FAQ_1faq_port_pass.html

Атмеловский мануал говорит, что порты разрешается передавать в функции, как указатели. Тип указателя - `volatile uint8_t *`. Вот так и передавайте ваш порт в вашу функцию. По ссылке и примеры можно посмотреть.

```
void chgBit(uint8_t value, volatile uint8_t *port, uint8_t pin)
{
  if (value)
    *port |= _BV(pin);
  else
    *port &= ~_BV(pin);
}
...
chgBit(1, &PORTB, 1);
chgBit(0, &PORTB, 1);
chgBit(0, &PORTB, 1);
chgBit(1, &PORTB, 1);
```

Comment: Но функция принимает аргумент port , в котором идет адрес порта.
Или это нужно делать через указатели?

Comment: @segar, смотря что вы хотите с этим номером сделать. Из текущего кода это совершенно непонятно.

Comment: @segar: Какой же это "адрес порта"? Параметр `port` у вас - обыкновенная переменная типа `char`, ничем не отличающаяся от любой другой переменной типа `char`. Вы ее инициализируете при вызове путем чтение значения из порта. Кроме этой незначительной детали эта переменная никакого отношения к порту не имеет.

Comment: Можно ли это сделать "через указатели" зависит от того, что скрывается за макро `PORTB` и документровано ли результирующее значение `PORTB`. Если это действительно просто некое lvalue, то да, можно сделать через указатель `&PORTB`. Но является ли такое обращение с `PORTB` "разрешенным" - не знаю.

Comment: PORTB определяется как `#define PORTB _SFR_IO8(0x18)` и насколько я знаю, является адресом в пространстве данных гарвардской машины.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, увы.

```
    00000051  IN R30,0x18       In from I/O location 
00000052  LDI R31,0x00      Load immediate 
    *port |= _BV(pin);
00000053  LDD R24,Z+0       Load indirect with displacement 
00000054  ORI R24,0x02      Logical OR with immediate 
00000055  STD Z+0,R24       Store indirect with displacement 
     chgBit(0,PORTB,1);
00000056  IN R30,0x18       In from I/O location 
00000057  LDI R31,0x00      Load immediate 
    *port &= ~_BV(pin);
00000058  LDD R24,Z+0       Load indirect with displacement 
00000059  ANDI R24,0xFD     Logical AND with immediate 
0000005A  STD Z+0,R24       Store indirect with displacement 
     chgBit(0,PORTB,1);
0000005B  IN R30,0x18       In from I/O location 
0000005C  LDI R31,0x00      Load immediate
```

Он их должен OUT выводить командой, а он их куда то в оперативку по левому адресу. В любом случае спасибо, дальше думаю сам нарою, вопрос вы решили, спасибо.

Comment: Ым... Почему у вас в вызове функции в качестве аргумента указано `PORTB`, а не `&PORTB`, как у меня в примере??? Неудивительно, что вас получается "левый адрес" (диагностику от компилятора вы просто проигнорировали?). И согласно атмеловским докам, для работы с замапленными в память портами можно использовать как инструкции `IN/OUT`, так и инструкции `LD/ST`. Надо только помнить, что у `IN/OUT` есть ограничения по адресации.

Comment: Простите, не заметил.  Да, теперь идеально.

Компилятор проглядел ибо сразу в симулятор прыгает, виноват.

Спасибо огромное.